# Is there a way to import Data from ASC document with VBA and adapt the time data according to the Date last modified?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA code to import Data from several ASC files into an Excel Worksheet. The data contains time in seconds(first column) and a value in the next column (so only the first two columns are important).

This is how the files look like:

```
0.550000  -674.465088  0.000000  0.000000  3.620000  60.700005  
1.550000  -674.288147  0.000000  0.000000  3.620000  60.700005  
2.550000  -673.940491  0.000000  0.000000  3.620000  60.700005  
3.550000  -673.702515  0.000000  0.000000  3.620000  60.700005  
4.550000  -673.909851  0.000000  0.000000  3.610000  60.700005  
5.550000  -674.111267  0.000000  0.000000  3.610000  60.700005  
6.550000  -674.038147  0.000000  0.000000  3.610000  60.700005  
7.550000  -674.214966  0.000000  0.000000  3.610000  60.700005  
8.550000  -674.227173  0.000000  0.000000  3.610000  60.700005  
9.550000  -674.001587  0.000000  0.000000  3.630000  60.700005  

0.550000  -621.436279  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  61.000000  
1.550000  -621.064148  0.000000  0.000000  3.700000  61.000000  
2.550000  -621.424133  0.000000  0.000000  3.700000  61.000000  
3.550000  -621.094666  0.000000  0.000000  3.700000  61.000000  
4.550000  -621.088562  0.000000  0.000000  3.700000  61.000000  
5.550000  -621.204468  0.000000  0.000000  3.700000  61.000000  
6.550000  -621.747437  0.000000  0.000000  3.660000  61.000000  
7.550000  -621.479004  0.000000  0.000000  3.660000  61.000000  
8.550000  -621.387512  0.000000  0.000000  3.660000  61.000000  
9.550000  -620.777161  0.000000  0.000000  3.660000  61.000000  

0.550000  -613.312195  0.000000  0.000000  3.730000  60.900002  
1.550000  -613.232910  0.000000  0.000000  3.730000  60.900002  
2.550000  -613.208435  0.000000  0.000000  3.730000  60.900002  
3.550000  -613.238953  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  60.900002  
4.550000  -613.293945  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  60.900002  
5.550000  -613.428101  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  60.900002  
6.550000  -613.507385  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  60.900002  
7.550000  -613.324402  0.000000  0.000000  3.790000  60.900002  
8.550000  -613.550110  0.000000  0.000000  3.910000  60.900002  
9.550000  -613.306152  0.000000  0.000000  3.910000  60.900002
```

These are the beginnings of 3 files.
The problem that I am facing is, that with each file the time starts from the beginning (0,55) but the measurement, that the files are based on was meant to be ongoing and so are the values that stand beside the time - there has been a break of some minutes after each measurement. So the idea would be to import the data of all files, and have the DateCreated of the first file as starting point and then continuing time values by assuming that the next measurement was started at its DateCreated.

My VBA knowledge is really basic (contains about a week of reading and watching youtube tutorials). I have tried different approaches and at the moment have a code that imports the data from each file and starts it at the cells of my excel sheet that I tell it to start at. I've written this code using the recorder but I could imagine there are ways that allow me to do it in a much simpler way.

I have a worksheet "database" where my data is imported to and a worksheet called "admin" where I write the path, name of the sheet, to which the data should be imported to and the row, in which the imported data of each file should start at.

I haven't found a way to import each DateCreated of the files in order to use them for creating an ongoing time. An additional problem that I have found here is that the DateCreated can only be shown in hhmmss, and to do calculations with it I would have to adapt the time column of the imported data(which is given in seconds only) in order to make it comparable to the DateCreated Data.

```
Sub ImportAllFiles()
For rep = 4 To 11

    Dim file_name As String
    Dim row_number As String
    Dim output_sheet As String

    file_name = Sheets("Admin").Range("B" & rep).Value
    output_sheet = Sheets("Admin").Range("C" & rep).Value
    row_number = Sheets("Admin").Range("D" & rep).Value


With Sheets(output_sheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + file_name, Destination:=Sheets(output_sheet).Range("$A$" + row_number))

    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True

    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Next rep

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

A perfect result for me would be, to put the path of my folder, which contains all my files, in a cell and have the Data of all my files in the folder imported.
Instead of always starting at 0.55 it should be an ongoing column of time from the first file (beginning of the measurement) to the end of the last file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal as understood by me could be achieved with multiple ways. But since I have some prejudice (may be unjustified) to handle text files directly without opening them in excel and only use the required data to populate excel cells, I would do it the following way

1. Select the text files with File Dialog (all files sometimes poses problem)
2. Sorting the files as per date created
3. Opening the files with FSO as Text Stream
4. Process Each line by Calculating absolute date time by adding Time elapsed  (column 1 of text file) with file creation date time.
5. Write to excel cells only required data.

May please add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"  (VBA project Window - Tools - Reference and add) 
The code may be modified for Actual Sheet names, folder names, row and column details etc.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim Fso As FileSystemObject, fl As File, Txtfl As TextStream
Dim path As String, Rw As Long, StRow As Long
Dim FNames() As Variant, Arr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp1 As Variant, temp2 As Variant
Dim line As String, tm As Date, ldate As Date
Dim Fdate As Date, Fname As String, Ws As Worksheet
Dim Outputsheet As String
Outputsheet = "Sheet1"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
path = "C:\users\user\Desktop\Folder1"
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Outputsheet)
StRow = 2

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .InitialFileName = path
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.Txt;*.Csv", 1
     If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
     ReDim FNames(1 To 2, 1 To .SelectedItems.Count) As Variant

        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        FNames(1, i) = .SelectedItems(i)
        Set fl = Fso.GetFile(FNames(1, i))
        FNames(2, i) = fl.DateCreated
       ' Debug.Print FNames(1, i) & " - " & Format(FNames(2, i), "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:Mm:ss")
        Next
    End With

    'Bubble Sort files list in order of date cteated
     For i = 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
     temp1 = FNames(1, i)
     temp2 = FNames(2, i)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
        If FNames(2, j) < temp2 Then
        FNames(1, i) = FNames(1, j)
        FNames(2, i) = FNames(2, j)
        FNames(1, j) = temp1
        FNames(2, j) = temp2
        End If
        Next j
     Next i

    ldate = 0
    Rw = StRow
    For i = 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
    Fname = FNames(1, i)
    Fdate = CDate(FNames(2, i))
    'Open each file in order of creation date
    Set Txtfl = Fso.OpenTextFile(FNames(1, i), ForReading)
        While Not Txtfl.AtEndOfStream ' while we are not finished reading through the file
        line = Txtfl.ReadLine
            ' Convert multiple spaces to single space
            Do While InStr(1, line, "  ") > 0
            line = Replace(line, "  ", " ")
            Loop

        Arr = Split(line, " ")
            'if line have significant data
            If UBound(Arr) >= 0 Then
            'calculate Time by adding second value at column 1 with file creation datetime
            tm = DateAdd("s", CDbl(Arr(0)), Fdate)
            Debug.Print tm, Arr(0)
                'Import data only if its time > than last imported data
                If DateDiff("s", tm, ldate) < 0 Then
                ldate = tm
                'write date to excel cells (modify to your requirement)
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = tm
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Arr(0)
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 3).Value = Arr(1)
                'Ws.Cells(Rw, 4).Value = Arr(2)
                '
                '
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 7).Value = Fname
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 8).Value = Fdate
                Rw = Rw + 1
                End If
            End If
        Wend
    Txtfl.Close
    Next i

Set Fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Result in excel sheet will be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRhY.png) (as tested with sample data)

However the simplest approach may be to import text files in excel with conventional text handling and finally filter and sort data on the time field (column) calculated by adding file creation time with 1st column of data (i.e. seconds elapsed). May be some one should also provide an other answer in this respect. I only shared my favorite approach to handle similar data.

Edit: The last part of the code is modified to get corrected time. The code for German language setting is incorporated in the function added.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test2()
Dim Fso As FileSystemObject, fl As File, Txtfl As TextStream
Dim path As String, Rw As Long, StRow As Long
Dim FNames() As Variant, Arr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp1 As Variant, temp2 As Variant
Dim Line As String, tm As Date, ldate As Date
Dim Fdate As Date, Fname As String, Ws As Worksheet
Dim Outputsheet As String
Outputsheet = "Sheet1"
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject")
path = "C:\users\user\Desktop\Folder1"
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Outputsheet)
StRow = 2

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .InitialFileName = path
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.Txt;*.Csv", 1
     If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
     ReDim FNames(1 To 2, 1 To .SelectedItems.Count) As Variant

        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        FNames(1, i) = .SelectedItems(i)
        Set fl = Fso.GetFile(FNames(1, i))
        FNames(2, i) = fl.DateCreated
       ' Debug.Print FNames(1, i) & " - " & Format(FNames(2, i), "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:Mm:ss")
        Next
    End With

    'Bubble Sort files list in order of date cteated
     For i = 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
     temp1 = FNames(1, i)
     temp2 = FNames(2, i)
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
        If FNames(2, j) < temp2 Then
        FNames(1, i) = FNames(1, j)
        FNames(2, i) = FNames(2, j)
        FNames(1, j) = temp1
        FNames(2, j) = temp2
        End If
        Next j
     Next i


    Dim Fulltxt As String, LineArr As Variant, TimeOffset As Double
    ldate = 0
    Rw = StRow
    For i = 1 To UBound(FNames, 2)
    Fname = FNames(1, i)
    Fdate = CDate(FNames(2, i))
    'Open each file in order of creation date
    Set Txtfl = Fso.OpenTextFile(FNames(1, i), ForReading)
    Fulltxt = Txtfl.ReadAll
    Txtfl.Close
    LineArr = Split(Fulltxt, vbCrLf)
    TimeOffset = 0

        ' Look for last significant line from last line
        For j = UBound(LineArr) To 0 Step -1
            If Trim(LineArr(j)) <> "" Then
            Line = ClearDoubleSpace(CStr(LineArr(j)))
            TimeOffset = Split(Line, " ")(0)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next

        For j = 0 To UBound(LineArr)
        Line = ClearDoubleSpace(CStr(LineArr(j)))
        If Trim(Line) <> "" Then  'not a blank line
        Arr = Split(Line, " ")
            If UBound(Arr) >= 0 Then  'if line have significant data
            'calculate Time by adding second value at column 1 with file creation datetime
            tm = DateAdd("s", CDbl(Arr(0)) - TimeOffset, Fdate)
            Debug.Print tm, Arr(0), Fdate
                'Import data only if its time > than last imported data
                If DateDiff("s", tm, ldate) < 0 Then
                ldate = tm
                'write date to excel cells (modify to your requirement)
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value = tm
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Arr(0)
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 3).Value = Arr(1)
                'Ws.Cells(Rw, 4).Value = Arr(2)
                '
                '
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 7).Value = Fname
                Ws.Cells(Rw, 8).Value = Fdate
                Rw = Rw + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Next j

    Next i

Set Fso = Nothing
End Sub
Private Function ClearDoubleSpace(Line As String) As String
 Line = Trim(Line)
 ' Convert multiple spaces to single space
 Do While InStr(1, Line, "  ") > 0
 Line = Replace(Line, "  ", " ")
 Loop
 'Replace decimal Separator with Geramn
 If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then Line = Replace(Line, ".", ",") ' , 1, 1)
 ClearDoubleSpace = Line
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code works perfectly as it was imagined by me. What I may add: I wasn't clear enough about the files that I was dealing with: they were .asc files and not .txt - i just added the filter *.asc. Additionally, the code didn't work at first when the language setting of my computer was German - after resetting it to English, the code did exactly what it should and what my goal was at the start. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome, Glad to be of some kind of help. But I am  not clear about the language setting problem. May give some more details for future readers and to keep me updated with the topics. If it solved your problem may please accept the answer by clicking tick mark beside answer to adhere to SO spirit. Also request @PEH to kindly share his expertise / info regarding, how opening a text file in FSO,processing text with split depends on language setting? Or is it Date functions like `DateAdd` etc? May kindly throw some light on it.

Comment: when running it in german language settings, the error window shows "run time error 6" - if I start debugging, it takes me to the 
DateAdd function; to be exact: 

'tm = DateAdd("s", CDbl(Arr(0)), Fdate)'

could you maybe help me out in what I would have to change to run it in german language settings as well?
if I do run it (ignoring the error window) the calculations of the ongoing time column are wrong like this
27.11.2017 21:52
09.12.2017 11:38
21.12.2017 01:25
01.01.2018 15:12
13.01.2018 04:58

Comment: I am not sure, But I tried with changing my setting to German. If in German setting your decimal separator is .Comma(,) and the ASC files used decimal separator as period(.) , then add this line.`line = Replace(line, ".", ",") ` after the line `line = Txtfl.ReadLine`. It worked in my system with  language setting as German. And Please let me know the outcome.

Comment: Better to make it `If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then line = Replace(line, ".", ",")`

Comment: I tried both of the options you listed and they both worked in a way that I do no get an error window and the calculation of the ongoing time in the first column is correct. However,  the Comma is eliminated from the second row of the second column on as well as in the whole third column.
second column: 0,550000
1 550 000
2 550 000
3 550 000
4 550 000

third column: -674 465 088
-674 288 147
-673 940 491
-673 702 515
-673 909 851

Comment: May be we are missing something about language setting. It worked correctly  in my PC setting language as German. How another hunch .only if time calculation part is is  OK. then replace only 1st (.) with (,) May try  with `If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then line = Replace(line, ".", ",", 1, 1)`

Comment: This solved the problem for the third column which is now correctly listed and the second column is still:  0,550000 1 550 000 2 550 000 3 550 000 4 550 000
But the second one isn't important as long as the ongoing time in the first column is calculated correctly.

Comment: I would have another inquiry about the code but please don't feel obliged to take care of it because you've already helped me out incredibly. Just in case: I was told the measurement didn't start at the DateCreated(which instead is basically the end of each measurement), but the correct Time for the start would be the DateCreated minus the Value of seconds that is written in the last row of the first column - in case of the samples i listed in my question: DateCreated - 9.550000+0,550000= Starting Time of the first measurement. Would it be possible to adapt the code for that case?

Comment: That's the 1st though I had when start writing the code. Edited code for that and tested OK in in English setting. And always glad to be all  any help within context and also feel sorry for not being able to solve the German Setting problem fully.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, this is exactly what I was looking for.